# Determining Dynamic DoubleAnimation 'From' Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas, code-behind

I have a WPF `Canvas` with a `TextBlock` nested within it.
The textblock has it's content set dynamically, and it's properties set from code-behind. 
Dependant on the content, it's width could be anything.

I'm using a `DoubleAnimation` to move the textblock from right to left within the canvas, giving the impression of a scolling marquee. 
I need the text to always start from the far right of the canvas, as though appearing from outside the screen, but to do this I have to set the `DoubleAnimation.From` property. 
Given that the width of the textblock is variable, **how can I set the `from property` to change as the width does?**

**Edit**
Current animation code -

```
DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
doubleAnimation.From = ??;
doubleAnimation.To = ??;
doubleAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.Parse("0:0:30"));
tbe.BeginAnimation(Canvas.RightProperty, doubleAnimation);
```

Comment: What property do you animate?

Comment: @Dominik I've updated question with current code :)